# jQuery Mobile after page is shown event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jquery Mobile (I'm familiar with jquery though) and I cannot find an event that runs after the page is shown. I'm using jStorage to store some data and I want on load to check if there is any data and if there is to show something different in the page (like add elements to a list).

But the $(document).ready does not work if I change the page (meaning the hash changes).

EDIT: 
I've already tried the pageshow event

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert('TEST');
});
```

But it happens before the content is put in the HTML.

Comment: `pageshow` should fire AFTER the transition completes. How are you generating the page?

Comment: maybe add some code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Damn, I actually found the answer, It was because I used a div with the id "list-content" and the id was actually doubled (because jquery mobile was keeping the old page) and when I edited the content it edited the first (the hidden one)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html) (which is always a good place to start):

> **pagebeforeshow**
>
> Triggered on the page being shown, before its transition begins.
>
> **pagebeforehide**
>
> Triggered on the page being hidden, before its transition begins.
>
> **pageshow**
>
> Triggered on the page being shown, after its transition completes.
>
> **pagehide**
>
> Triggered on the page being hidden, after its transition completes.

Comment: I've already tried that. Check my edit, but that happens before the page html is put.

Comment: Same problem here, need to do some recalculations on pageload. Pageshow triggers after trransition before the load.